# Normal subgroup in graph automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

Let be $ \Gamma$ a graph, and define $G:=Aut( \Gamma)$. If $N\triangleleft G$, I need to answer if $N$ correspond to a graphical minor of $\Gamma$. I also need to answer the question to $G/N$.

I could not relate the automorphisms of the subgroup $N$ with the structure of the graph $\Gamma$

Comment: Hint: look at the orbits of points under the action by $N$.

Comment: Thanks. What does mean that $N$ correspond to a graphical minor of $ \Gamma$.?